# Hide Area in URL using AttributeRouting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

We are using Areas to version an API written in ASP.NET MVC3 with AttributeRouting to define our routes.

Right now we have a "v1" area that is our first version of API. When we got to v2, we will copy over v1 and make modifications.

I want to use the same versioning for a website and I don't want the /v1 in the route.

My question is, how do I hide the Area in my URL so I can call

```
mywebsite.com/Users/1
```

instead of

```
mywebsite.com/v1/Users/1
```

Here is what I have in my controller

```
    [RouteArea("/")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /v1/Home/
        [GET("")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

and here is what I get when I try to visit mywebsite.com/

[image: error]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
[RouteArea("AreaName", AreaUrl = "")]
```

By default, areas are prefixed with the area name. The AreaUrl property lets you override that. I'll update the wiki here: https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Areas

Sorry for the confusion!

Also, you shouldn't add forward-slashes at the beginning or end of any urls defined via AR. Your stack trace dump highlights that MVC is looking for views in a folder named "/". If you want an empty url, just use "".