# Asp.Net Mvc hiding some part for Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a url like : http://www.example.com/Bank/Sales/Home

We need the url to be in like :  http://www.example.com/Sales/Home removing ‘Bank’.

How we can achieve this using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You have a string variable storing the url value and you want to remove a specific word from that ? Did you look into string methods ?

Comment: The high level answer is probably to change your routing. The more detailed answer depends on what your current routing looks like.

Comment: Yep, looks like a duplicate of this question if `Bank` is an area.  But we can only guess with amount of info provided: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10215144/84206

Comment: Actually we have two application as local and bank

the first application which has a controller and when we redirect from local application of 'http://www.example.com/Home' from homecontroller to bank application.

the bank application which has Area 'sales' with 'Home' controller and the url changes from 'http://www.example.com/Home' to 'http://www.example.com/Bank/Sales/Home' we need to remove the 'Bank' from the url.

kindly help